# Android Studio Installed plugins can't able to use

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins

Searching for a good Android studio plugins so far and got it some interesting one to use it for code generation, installed and used for some time.

i have used

> **Android Code Generator Plugin**

But after updated to 1.5.0 the plugins not seems to show it from the menu itself.

Here is the screenshot while its working(showing the menu of plugin)

But after update to 1.5.0 the menu is just disappers..

[image] [image]

I have uninstalled and installed the plugins many times,

[image]

Anyone help me regarding this issue, can't get any content describing this issues.

Comment: go to settings, then plugins, your plugin may be out-of-date. That's the reason why you don't see it in menu

Comment: Look, your plugin like Butterknife  Zelezny has different icon than Android SDK and Coverage, so it seems to be that Android Studio 1.5 turn them off

Comment: No its not like that, the icons are showing to indicate its a downloaded plugin, .ignore plugin is working fine(as u can see in my right side 2nd screenshot). The other icons labelled with "jb" to indicate its a jetBrains plugin(the vendor of the IDE)

Answer (score 0):

Since the plugin is supported only for the xml's in layout/ folder and not supporting the other xml's in layout-large or layout-xlarge folder. The documentation of the plugin is not supposed to be clear is the problem of the issue..